# C - For loop only runs once against array I amend

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Firstly, apologies for possibly a simple question and bad code, like most people who post questions I am very new to the language in question.

**Purpose of code:**

To create a program that simulates process scheduling. This specific instance is to mimic First Come First Served Scheduling. The datasets in question are both ordered (e.g. PID's 0 to 5 all arrive in sequence) and unordered (e.g. 3 can arrive before 1 etc).

To achieve this I have tried to find the smallest entry in my arrival time array to ensure the entries are processed in order. Because of this I am amending the arrays as they are running through the for loop, changing the smallest value so it is not run twice (I believe this may be my problem but am unsure)

**Specific loop I am having issues with:**

```
for (i = 1; i < processes; i++) {
    atperm[position] = at[position];
    smallestentry();
    wt[position] = btt - at[position]; //wait time = total burst time - arrival time
    btt += bt[position]; //total burst time = total burst time + burst time
    awt += wt[position]; //average wait time = average wait time + wait time
    tat[position] = wt[position] + bt[position]; //turn around time = wait time + burst time
    atat += tat[position]; //average turn around time = average turn around time + turn around time
    changeline(position);
}
```

**Full Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* 
 * WT - Wait Time (TAT -BT)
 * BT - Bust Time
 * AT - Arrival Time
 * TAT - Turn Around Time (CT - AT)
 * AWT - Average Wait Time
 * ATAT - Average Turn Around Time
 */

int wt[10], bt[10], at[10], atperm[10], tat[10], processes, smallest, i, position;
float awt, atat;

void input() {
    printf("Enter number of processes:\n");
    scanf("%d", &processes);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < processes; i++) {
        printf("Enter burst time of process %d:", i + 1); //increase i by 1 but dont save
        scanf("%d", &bt[i]);
        printf("Enter arrival time of process %d:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &at[i]);
    }
}

void changeline(int position) {
    at[position] = 999;

    printf("AT\tBT\tWT\tTAT\tAT\n");
    for (i = 0; i < processes; i++) {
        printf("%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\n", at[i], bt[i], wt[i], tat[i], atperm[i]);
    }
}

void smallestentry() {
    smallest = at[0];
    for (i = 0; i < processes; i++) {
        if (smallest > at[i]) {
            smallest = at[i];
            position = i;
        }
    }
}

void calculate() {
    smallestentry();
    wt[position] = 0; //sets the first entry in wait time array to equal 0
    atat = tat[position] = bt[position]; //sets the first entries in atat and tat array to equal first bt entry
    int btt = bt[position]; //to store total burst time sum
    atperm[position] = at[position];
    changeline(position);

    for (i = 1; i < processes; i++) {
        atperm[position] = at[position];
        smallestentry();
        wt[position] = btt - at[position]; //wait time = total burst time - arrival time
        btt += bt[position]; //total burst time = total burst time + burst time
        awt += wt[position]; //average wait time = average wait time + wait time
        tat[position] = wt[position] + bt[position]; //turn around time = wait time + burst time
        atat += tat[position]; //average turn around time = average turn around time + turn around time
        changeline(position);
    }
    atat /= processes; // atat = atat / processes
    awt /= processes; // awt = awt / processses
}

int main() {
    printf("FCFS CPU Scheduling Algorithm\n");
    input();
    calculate();
}
```

Comment: Your loop looks strange. It doesn't use the counter `i`, but it does use `position`, which is not being updated.

Comment: First Come First Serve is generally used for queue which are FIFO (first in first out). You should check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/queue_program_in_c.htm .
I suggest using a queue to order your wait times like a physical 'line queue' that forms at, for example, a doctors office. I would do this to get started then figure it out from there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `smallestentry()` updates `position`.

Comment: It would be clearer if `smallestentry()` returned the new position instead of setting a global variable. You would then write `position = smallestentry();`.

Comment: Forgot to describe nature of malfunction; please correct

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is that you used i as a global variable.

```
int wt[10], bt[10], at[10], atperm[10], tat[10], processes, smallest, i, position;
```

in the middle of your loop you called the function smallestentry() which also used i:

```
void smallestentry() {
smallest = at[0];
    for (i = 0; i < processes; i++) {
        if (smallest > at[i]) {
            smallest = at[i];
            position = i;
        }
    }
}
```

After this function ended the value of i was changed so the loop only ran once.

I found the problem by putting `printf("%d",i);` inside the loop.

you can solve this by changing i to a local variable inside your functions.

(Sorry for any bad phrasing, this is my first answer.)